# Computing the degree of map of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X=\{(t,t^2,t^3):t\in\mathbb{C}\}$ be an affine curve and consider the morphism $f:X\to\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$, $(t,t^2,t^3)\mapsto t$. How to compute the degree of $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f:X\to Y$ be a finite morphism of curves, then the degree if $f$ is defined to be the degree of the field extension $[K(X):K(Y)].$

In this particular case, both $X$ and $Y$ are affine varieties. So $K(X)$ and $K(Y)$ are just the field of fractions of their respective co-ordinate rings. It can be proved that the co-ordinate ring of $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[t],$ the same as $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb C}.$ So the degree is $1.$